# Must be of the type array, null returned Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have a model file and I am requesting an api link in this file. But I keep getting null error all the time

I am sending data to apiRequest method from the controller.

**Test.php model is below**

```
static function apiRequest(string $url , array $data): array
    {

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Accept: */*",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        $response = json_decode($response , true);

        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        dd($response);

        /* if ($err) {
            return ["error" => true];
        } else {
            return $response;
        } */
    }
```

The controller file that I sent data is as follows.

```
public function workplaces(){

        try {

            $workplaces = Workplace::all();

                foreach ($workplaces as $workplace){

                     $api_arr=[
                        'username' => $workplace->username,
                        'password' => $workplace->password
                    ];

                    $api_response= Test::apiRequest('http://api.testlocal.com/api/login',$api_arr);
                    Workplace::where('id',$workplace['id'])->update([
                       'api_token' => $api_response['reel_token']
                    ]);
                }

                  $workplaceses = Workplace::all();

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'workplaces' => $workplaceses,
                'success' => true
            ]);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'error' => true
            ]);
        }

    }
```

I need to send $ api_response data but it gets null. Where could I have made a mistake

Comment: Please add logs to your curl request and see what new information you get.

Comment: The error you shown doesn't match the code that you provided. The `$api_arr` provided to the function here is always `['username' => $workplace->username, 'password' => $workplace->password];`. It will never be `null`. The `null` issue is certainly generated elsewhere. And you need to show the relevant code in order for us to help.